# Dovecot/Pigeonhole: How to specify default directory permission for newly created ./sieve directory for fresh uers?

Tags: dovecot, file-permissions, sieve

I am running Dovecot 2.3.20 with enabled Sieve support. I am using virtual mail boxes for several hosted virtual domains. The system account and group which owns (shall own) the directories and mail files on the filesystem is `vmail:vmail`.

I want all directories, incl. the directory which stores the user-specific sieve scripts, to be group readable and executable. However, if a fresh user accesses its mail account for the first time Dovecot creates the sieve directory within the user's mail home direcoty with permission `2700`, i.e. the group `vmail` has no read access. How do I change that?

*Background*

The relevant Dovecot settings are

```
home=/var/spool/mail/vmail/%d/%{ldap:uid}
mail_location = sdbox:~/Maildir
sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
```

The permissions on the top directory are as

```
server ~ # ls -lhad /var/spool/mail/vmail/
drwxr-s--- 4 vmail vmail 60 22. Dec 18:43 /var/spool/mail/vmail/
```

If I add a new account to LDAP and the relevant directories do not yet exist, Dovecot creates the following directory structure

```
server ~ # ls -lhR /var/spool/mail/vmail/my-test.tld
/var/spool/mail/vmail/my-test.tld:
insgesamt 0
drwxr-s--- 4 vmail vmail 56 16. Jan 00:45 john.doe

/var/spool/mail/vmail/my-test.tld/john.doe:
insgesamt 0
drwxr-s--- 3 vmail vmail 164 14. Jan 18:37 Maildir
drwx--S--- 3 vmail vmail  35 14. Jan 18:48 sieve     # <-- this should be drwxr-s---, too

/var/spool/mail/vmail/my-test.tld/john.doe/Maildir
insgesamt 0

/var/spool/mail/vmail/my-test.tld/john.doe/sieve
insgesamt 0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `umask`
There is a very good write-up with examples [here](https://linuxize.com/post/umask-command-in-linux/)

Comment: I doubt that the problem is umask related. As ar as I can tell the umask value for the system account which runs the Dovecot daemon is 0022. If the directory was created accordingly, the permissions should be 0755. It rather seems that the daemon deliberately sets the directory permissions to a stricter value after creation. Hence, umask does not help here.